# Xamarin forms: IOS won't load webview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a webview on a page that opens with data from a previous page. It works on Android and with IOS the screen remains white. I have already searched a bit and found out that it can be due to the events. I use the events : OnAppearing, Navigating and Navigated.

```
<WebView x:Name="webview" 
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 Navigating="webOnNavigating"
                 Navigated="webOnEndNavigating"
                 IsVisible="False"/>

public WebviewPage(String link, String username, String password)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        colorLogOutButton(link);
        linkForApi = link;
        compLink = link + "/Login1.aspx" + "?ID=" + GUID + "&Username=" + username + "&Password=" + password;
        webview.Source = compLink;


    }
```

Comment: Sorry dude, English please :)

Comment: Please write in English, anyway, it's probably related to the ATS settings of your application. The link you're trying to open is in HTTP?

Comment: Sorry guys wrong text :)

Comment: Are you loading an HTTP page?

Comment: Yes the link is HTTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add an exception to the Apple Transport Security (ATS) in order to display HTTP content in your application. You can do that modifying your .plist and adding the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` key. Something like that:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm still a beginner where do I add this?

Comment: The info.plist (in the main folder of the iOS project) should contain a bunch of key/values like CFBundleIdentifier, MinimumOSVersion and so so.. It shouldn't be empty, and you have to add the code of the answer there.

Comment: @Markus3D open the `info.plist` file with Notepad or something similar